# Unable to access the resources file in jar after packaging : FileSystemNotFoundException

Tags: java, html, eclipse, jar, executable-jar

Hi I am working on developing a small java application (kinda new to this ) which takes an input file and gives out an web page. Here the HTML template and an image file to the web page are in resource folder.

[image]

Below is the way I am accessing the html template file in my code.(I need to read the HTML template as an string)

```
{       
        String htmlString;
    
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        URL fileurl = classLoader.getResource("template.html");
        htmlString = String.join("\n", Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileurl.toURI()))); 

    }
```

the code works fine when ran from eclipse but fails when I run it as an jar.(java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException:)
kindly help me in accessing the template file from resources folder and also note that the html takes an image from the same folder. Now the template and image file must be packaged and should be able to run as a single JAR .

update :
Extracted the jar file with 7-zip to see the contents. I can see the files in resources are available with the jar
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the contents of your final jar? Does the template.html exist in the root of your jar file?

Comment: yes I saw the contents unzipping through 7-zip.  template.html is present inside the Jar.

Comment: @zaerymoghaddam I have attached the contents of the jar . Let me know if anything wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You have packaged everything into a jar so the pathnames to resources is no longer a valid path to a file. If you added this logging you would see that the path to the jar entry says something like `jar:file:/C:/path/to/your.jar!/template.html` which cannot be opened by `Files.readAllLines`:

```
URI uri = fileurl.toURI();
System.out.println("uri="+uri);
```

The solution is easy, just locate the resource as `InputStream` which must be on the classpath:

```
String htmlString;
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
try(InputStream in = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("template.html")) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    in.transferTo(out);
    htmlString = new String(out.toByteArray()); // as platform encoding
}
```

This works if the `res` directory is part of your classpath when you run the code in exploded directory, and works in JAR file if the contents of "res" are inside the jar.